# How do I temporarily turn off an IDENTITY column in EF Code First?

Tags: ef-code-first

I'm creating a rewrite of an existing application in EF Code First, but I need to import some of the data from the existing application's database.  Here's the definition of my entity class:

```
public class Business : EntityBase
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
```

Now, the imported records need to retain their `AccountNumber` value from the old system.  However, new values should use the `IDENTITY` value generated by the DB.

How do I turn off the `IDENTITY` while I'm importing old records, then turn it back on for the remainder of the lifetime of the application?  Executing this before importing the records has no effect:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("set identity_insert Businesses on");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Executing a `set identity_insert` command changes the behavior of SQL Server, but not the behavior of Entity Framework.

You have three choices for importing records:

- Use raw ADO.NET commands (not entities) or `ExecuteSqlCommand`.
- Use a different `DbContext`, in which you define the keys as non-generated.
- Use a different technology that's more suited for data conversion, like SSIS

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this same issue. In my case, I was using SQL Server CE. Here's a link to my solution:

[Inserting all rows of a DataTable into a SQL Server table, including Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419793/inserting-all-rows-of-a-datatable-into-a-sql-server-table-including-id-values/6949386#6949386) (scroll down to Edit 2)

This is basically Diego's solution #1 -- raw ADO.NET. It's not a great solution because you will need to customize the queries to account for any differences in databases, but hopefully it will help solve your problem for the moment.