# How to insert ID in EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key

I am trying something with EF 4.1 that should be relatively easy. I have a class like this

```
class Entity 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

The Id property should be the primary key in the DB and this all works. But when I insert new entities **with given IDs** EF4.1 ignores the ID and creates a new one. So I would like something like identity_insert?

Greeting,
Martijn

Comment: Does your EDM show the Id column as being the primary key? UPDATE: Sorry..just realized you're doing code-first.  Have you tried setting a [key] attribute on your Id to indicate to EF that Id is the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7151710/62024), but it's not clear from the text if you want to have a property that is **always** created by your code, or just sometimes (as it is in that question)